# TripIt Strategy for Omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I am new in Rails! I am using Omniauth and so far, nobody has done any TripIt strategies.

TripIt uses oAuth 1.0 and there is a omniauth-oauth that i am using!

So far i have this code:

```
require 'omniauth-oauth'
require 'multi_xml'

module OmniAuth
  module Strategies
    class Tripit < OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth
      option :name, "tripit"

      option :client_options, {
          :site => 'https://api.tripit.com',
          :request_token_path => '/oauth/request_token',
          :access_token_path => '/oauth/access_token',
          :authorize_path => '/oauth/confirm_access'
      }

      uid do
        request.params['username']
      end

      info do
        {
            :email => raw_info['feed']['entry']['content']['Email']['EmailAddress']
        }
      end

      extra do
        { 'raw_info' => raw_info }
      end

      def raw_info
        #@raw_info ||= MultiXml.parse(access_token.get("https://api.constantcontact.com/ws/customers/" + request.params['username'] + "/settings/emailaddresses").body)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I get an error:

```
consumer key not present in request
```

Any help on that?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: [omniauth-tripit](https://github.com/mrgilman/omniauth-tripit). It was just released.